# pandas dataframe conditional retrieval of value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There's a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Place':[1,2,5,6],
                'Event':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theatre', 'Comedy'],
                'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000, 2000]})
```

and two more variables which I get from user:

```
a=input("Enter Event:")
b=input("Enter Place:")
```

Now I want to create a list with [a,b,c] where c is `cost column` from df, for a unique combination of Event and Place

Output:

When a=Poetry and b=2, then `c should return 5000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply use `df['Cost'][(df['Event'] == a) & (df['Place'] == b)]`. It would filter the dataframe and returns the `Cost` column as a pandas series which satisfies the condition `(df['Event'] == a) & (df['Place'] == b)`. If there are no rows in the dataframe which satisfies the condition, it will return an empty pandas series.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for that:

```
def getval():
    try:
        a=input("Enter Event:")
        b=input("Enter Place:")
        return df.loc[df['Event'].eq(a) & df['Place'].eq(int(b)),'Cost']
    except ValueError:
        return 'Entry Not Found'

#Finally call the function:
getval()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, you can use:

```
a = 'Music'
b =  1

print(f"When a is {a} and b is {b} then C is --> ",
      int(df.loc[df['Event'].eq(a) & df['Place'].eq(int(b)),'Cost'].values))
```

Which prints:

```
When a is Music and b is 1 then C is -->  10000
```